# What's the radius of convergence for power series of $1/(1-(x+x^2))$? Is it symmetrical?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

When reading the section on composition of power series in Book **Calculus With Analytic Geometry** (George F. Simmons) (2nd edition, pp. 517), the author claimed you can replace $x$ in a power series $f(x):=\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j x^j$ with another power series $g(z):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$, and write the composition of two series as $h(z):=f\bigl(g(z)\bigr) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$. However, I have problem with radius of convergence of this new series.

To be concrete, suppose I want to know the power series of $1/(1-x-x^2)$. I start with $1/(1-x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i, |x|<1$, and then replace $x$ with $x+x^2$. Since the constant term of $x+x^2$ ($g(z)$ in the above paragraph) is zero, I can certainly rearrange $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (x+x^2)^i$ in terms of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k$. When does this new series converge? Suppose I compute $ |x+x^2|<1$, then I get $(-1-\sqrt{5})/2 < x < (-1+\sqrt{5})/2 $. But, is this inconsistent with the theorem that the radius of convergence for a power series is **symmetrical** (say $(-R,R)$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reciprocals of the poles of the denominator of this rational function are the roots of $X^2-X-1$, which are the golden ratio $\phi$ and its "conjugate" $-\phi^{-1}$. The largest in absolute value of these two is $\phi$, so the coefficients $c_n$ of your series are asymptotically $\sim c\phi^n$ for some $c\neq0$, and the radius of convergence is $\frac1\phi$.

You make an interesting observation that this convergence condition is not equivalent to $|x+x^2|<1$. Let's see what happens when you expand $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (x+x^2)^i$. You get $1+x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4-8x^5+\cdots$, which looks familiar; indeed it is $\sum_iF_{i+1}x^i$ where $F_i$ are the Fibonacci numbers (which indeed grow asymptotically as $\frac1{\sqrt5}\phi^n$). Now what happens if one sets $x=-1$, a value outside the radius of convergence, but which conveniently satisfies $|x+x^2|=0<1$? On one hand you have been expanding $\sum_{i=0}^\infty 0^i$ which should give $1$. On the other hand substituting $x=-1$ into the series gives $1-1+2-3+5-8+\cdots$ which diverges. What gives? Well if you try to find your powers of $x+x^2$ back in the power series, you can group together parts of several terms so that each group of terms (except the initial $1$) evaluates to $0$ for $x=-1$. But in order to do so, you have been, at $x=-1$, grouping together terms in an absolutely divergent series, and that is not allowed (and may produce a convergent series). Indeed an easier form of this swindle is
$$
  \begin{align}
  1-1+2-3+5-8-\cdots &= 1 - (0+1)+(1+1)-(1+2)+(2+3)-(3+5) \\
  &= 1+(-1+1)+(1-1)+(-2+2)+(3-3)+(-5+\cdots \\ &=1.
  \end{align}
$$

Your power series is divergent at$~x=-1$ (and indeed everywhere outside the interval $[-\frac1\phi,\frac1\phi]$).

Comment: So basically, the rearrangement of coefficients is sometimes invalid (say for $x=-1$), right?

Comment: Yes. Basically treating a power series like a formal power series is only valid within its radius of convergence (where it becomes an absolutely convergent series). Rearrangement of not absolutely convergent series is not allowed in general.

Answer (score 4):

**A start:** An approach that is useful in the analysis of series like yours is to find the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $1-x-x^2=0$, and then imagine using  the method of *partial fractions* to express $\frac{1}{x^2+x-1}$ as $\frac{A}{x-\alpha}+\frac{B}{x-\beta}$. To *imagine* is enough, for our purposes we  don't need to know $A$ and $B$

The interval of convergence can now be read off.

Comment: I think your method certainly works. Just don't know what's wrong with mine...

Comment: Thanks. But I think your method should give a convergence interval centered at zero...

Comment: Yes, indeed it does, since both expansions are about $x=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: the question says the series is convergent for instance at $x=-1$; this is wrong (as your answer implies). I've expanded my answer to address this in some detail.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Nice answer (yours below). The "rearrangement" argument of OP fails, because of the hidden negatives.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
the new series is convergent when $|x+x^2|<1$ anddivergent when $|x+x^2|>1$.